# JSP if always execute else statement

Tags: html, jsp

i'm building a website for a school project. I want to load the same page but in two different scenarios:

1. when the logged user wants to see his profile
2. when the page shows another user's profile

so i have the page `profile.jsp` with an `if`

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("u")!=null){ %>

   ---logged user stuff HTML---

<% } else{ %>

   ---user stuff HTML---

<% } %>
```

it always execute the `else` statement, and i'm sure that `request.getAttribute("u")` returns the right value.

[This is when i access the logged user's profile so the first one is the logged user (jack in this case) and the second is `request.getAttribute("u")` and here it should be null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIh4Q.png)

[The first one is the logged user, the second is `request.getAttribute("u")`, here is carl and it's right, but it doesn't what it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N57y.png)

Comment: If, as you said, you are sure the attribute `u` is in the request (when it comes to this statement) then we need more information to figure it out.  Just to humour me, can you print out the value of `u` for us? -> I.e. print it out like: `<%= request.getAttribute("u") %>` before the `if` statement

Comment: I would wager that 'u' is null. I'd advise two things: 1. Use JSTL's c:if statement. 2. Use more descriptive names than 'u'.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<% String msg2=(String)request.getAttribute("u");%>

        <% if ( (msg2==null || msg2.isEmpty()) ) { %> 
         // WHAT YOU ARE NOT LOGED IN             
        <% } else if(msg2!=null) { %>

         <% }  %>
```

Comment: Still not working, i've swapped the code that was in the else with the one in the if, and it shows the code the WAS in the else. So i think that there's a problem with the condition, or something else

Comment: this code I tested in my project and it work perfectly 
you have a problem in the file where you set this parameter (u)

Comment: This is the code that i use to set the variable `u`
`<a href="profile.jsp?u=<%out.println(autor);%>"><%out.println(autor);%> </a>`
Is it wrong like this ?

Comment: 1/what is autor a variable sent by the servlet ?
2/does in the link the value <%out.println(autor);%> appears correctly

Comment: `autor` is a value from a quey, and yes it's displayed correctly in url